# htaccess 301 domains to new domain, except for subdomain/folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to 301 redirect a couple of urls to their new home, however the client wants their old site active on archive.website.com (which points to website.com/archive directory).

I have tried the following code however it doesn't stop the `archive` request from being redirected. How can I achieve that any requests to `archive.website.com` or `website.com/archive` go to that folder whereas anything else redirects to `newdomain.com`?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/archive [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

This is the htaccess inside the `/archive` folder

```
RewriteOptions inherit

        # -- concrete5 urls start --
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
        # -- concrete5 urls end --

        # -- concrete5 urls start --
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
        # -- concrete5 urls end --

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: I can access `/archive` fine removing that but no luck with `archive.` Though I'm *not actually sure* what rule I need to add for that to work @anubhava

Comment: ok clarify what full URL is still redirecting to `newdomain.com`? Is there a .htaccess inside `archive/` directory as well?

Comment: olddomain.com and olddomain.co.uk are redirection to newdomain.com regardless of the request. However, I need archive.olddomain.com and archive.olddomain.co.uk to show the old site which is stored in the `archive` folder. Yes there is a htaccess file inside archive as this controls the CMS/page routing @anubhava

Comment: ok, can you show `archive/.htaccess` in your question.

Comment: Yeah sure, just a minute

Comment: Just added @anubhava

Comment: ok comment out `RewriteOptions inherit` line in `archive/.htaccess` and retest in a new browser.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, it just gives me "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN" :( @anubhava

Comment: Oh I really don't know what is `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` error as I haven't come across this error ever using `mod_rewrite`. Google says: **This error is most often caused by having no connection to the internet or a misconfigured network.**

Comment: That's annoying, I'll do some more digging. Nothing else wrong with the htaccess code though I assume?

Comment: No, nothing else, I can think of.